# Menu Call Back for Ajax not working

Tags: 7, routes, ajax

Below is the code in my module. I want to do an ajax posting to path test_call. But when am doing that am getting a 404 error message.

```
<?php

function callback_permission() {
  return array(
    'access simple page' => array(
      'title' => t('Access callback'),
      'description' => t('Allow users to access callback'),
    )
  );
}

function callback_menu() {

   $items = array();
   $items['test_call'] = array(

    'page callback' => 'callback_test',
    'access arguments' => array('access simple page'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );


  return $items;
}


function callback_test()
{

 return "success";

}
```

I am

Comment: Did you assign the right permissions to the the access callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu item looks fine so make sure you've done the usual things, make sure the module is installed and enabled, and make sure you clear Drupal's caches so the menu is rebuilt and your new item can be picked up.

On another note, if this callback is meant for AJAX you probably want to be printing something rather than returning it in your callback function. Something like this:

```
function callback_test() {
  print 'success';
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: I was having my module named callback. I changed that to another name and then cleared cache. Now it seems to work fine.